# Query DB to get multiple rows where timestamps are the same, and email addresses are the same

Tags: php, mysql, cron

```
<?php
$curr = time();

$time_query = "SELECT * FROM users ";

$time_query_result = mysql_query($time_query, $db) or 

die("Could not execute sql: $time_query"); 

$num_result = mysql_num_rows($time_query_result);

for ($i1=0; $i1 < $num_result; $i1++){

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($time_query_result); 


    if ($curr > $row["time"] + 259200)//Do if it has been three days since brochure was selected
    {
           $arr = implode (',', $row);//TURN THE ROW[BROCHURES] ARRAY INTO IMPLODE THING INSIDE THIS LOOP!?!?!
        echo $arr;
        $message1  = '<html><body><p>Brochure reminder</p>';
        $message1 .= 'Brochures:<br />'.$arr .$row["brochures"]. $row["time"];
        $message1 .= '</body></html>';
        // Mail it
        mail($row['email'], $subject, $message1, $headers);
    }

} ?>
```

So basically, I want to send an email to customers selecting a brochure. That part is done and fine, but I want them to receive another email after three days reminding them about the brochures they have chosen. I have set up a cron job so this piece of code gets repeated every three days.

When the mail is sent, it sends it to the correct person but the selected brochures are split into seperate emails. For example, if somebody selects 5 brochures, after three days they will reveice 5 seperate emails, with a different brochure in each one.

I need it so they receive all brochures in one email after three days. Would really appreciate this, been driving me mad for days. It seems like the answer could be really simple but I cant figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Another important thing to note is that in the database, if a person selects 5 brochures, it will create 5 rows in the database, each with the same timestamp etc... but the brochure will be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the time logic into your database query - there's no point in fetching ALL rows, only to throw away some (most? all?) of the rows if there's nothing to do:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE `time` < (now() - INTERVAL 3 DAY)
```

Once that's done, I'd suggest moving the actual mail() portion out of the database fetching loop, so that you can batch together each user's brochures first:

```
$users = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($time_query_result)) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row['userID'], $users)) {
        $users[$row['userID']] = array('email' => $row['email'], 'brochures' => array());
    $users[$row['userID']]['brochures'] = array('b' => $row['brochures'], 't' => $row['time']);
    }
}
```

You'd then loop over this $users array to build emails for the users:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
     $text = '<html><body><p>Brochure reminder</p>';
     $i = 1;
     foreach ($user['brochures'] as $brochure) {
        $text .= 'Brochures:<br />'.$i++ .$row['b']. $row['b'];
     }
     $text .= '</body></html>';
     mail($user['email'], $subject, $text, $headers);
}
```

This way, you fetch all the user details in one go. You then build a SINGLE email to each user, listing all of their brochures, and (hopefully) problem solved.

Comment: Sorry, thought enter would take me to a new line - new to this forum. Yeah I see what you mean by moving the time logic into the DB query, makes sense. That looks exactly like what I am looking for ha. Cant try it out yet but I will do tomorrow morning first thing and will post back! Thanks again.

Comment: @JamesG Welcome to StackOverflow. If you accidentally post a comment, you can edit it them within 5 minutes, just hover on your comment, click the edit option. You can also edit questions to add additional information so that you do not have to append comments.

Comment: @marc B Hi, I have the database query working ok, but its saying the "array_key_exists" needs another parameter. Never used this function before sorry..

Comment: I think its something to do with the userid row which it is getting from the DB, I have not got this, but I have one called ID which is an auto increment. I have added this but still doesnt work.. still not 100% what the second parameter is meant to be.

Comment: @jamesg: ah, right. the syntax is: `array_key_exists('key', $array)`. I'll fix up the answer.

Comment: @marc b - no problem mate, I think ive sorted it...

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($time_query_result)) { <br>
    
if (!array_key_exists($row["new"], $users)) { <br>

Thanks so much, really helped